# PHP : get parent child value

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I have an array like this

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => '1',
    'job_id' => 'J1',
    'parent_id' => '0',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'id' => '2',
    'job_id' => 'J2',
    'parent_id' => '0',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'id' => '3',
    'job_id' => 'J3',
    'parent_id' => '1',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'id' => '4',
    'job_id' => 'J4',
    'parent_id' => '2',
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'id' => '5',
    'job_id' => 'J5',
    'parent_id' => '3',
  ),
  5 => 
  array (
    'id' => '6',
    'job_id' => 'J6',
    'parent_id' => '1',
  ),
  6 => 
  array (
    'id' => '8',
    'job_id' => 'J8',
    'parent_id' => '7',
  ),
)
```

I am showing child record where parent_id is mention with it's parent records

Output

```
Array
(
[1] => Array
    (
        [job_id] => J1
        [parent_id] => 0
        [children] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [job_id] => J3
                        [parent_id] => 1
                        [children] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [job_id] => J5
                                        [parent_id] => 3
                                    )
                            )
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [job_id] => J6
                        [parent_id] => 1
                    )

            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [job_id] => J2
        [parent_id] => 0
        [children] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [job_id] => J4
                        [parent_id] => 2
                    )
            )
    )

)
```

Now I want - if parent_id mentioned but it's not available in given array then want to show records in main array in output not as child array

expecting output

```
Array
(
[1] => Array
    (
        [job_id] => J1
        [parent_id] => 0
        [children] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [job_id] => J3
                        [parent_id] => 1
                        [children] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [job_id] => J5
                                        [parent_id] => 3
                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [job_id] => J6
                        [parent_id] => 1
                    )

            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [job_id] => J2
        [parent_id] => 0
        [children] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [job_id] => J4
                        [parent_id] => 2
                    )

            )

    )
[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 8
        [job_id] => J8
        [parent_id] => 7
    )
 )
```

Here id 7 is not exist in error i want it as parent records with id as key. How to find that?

Code

```
function buildTree( $ar, $pid = 0 ) {
        $op = array();
        foreach( $ar as $item ) {
            echo '<pre>';
            //print_r($item);echo '<br>';//exit;
            if( $item['parent_id'] == $pid ) {
                $op[$item['id']] = array(
                    'job_id' => $item['job_id'],                       
                    'parent_id' => $item['parent_id']
                );
                // using recursion
                $children =  buildTree( $ar, $item['id'] );
                //print_r($children);
                $children = array_values($children);
                if( $children ) {
                    $op[$item['id']]['children'] = $children;
                }
            }
        }
        return $op;
 }
```

Comment: While you post your array, please do not use `var_dump` or `print_r` instead use `var_export` this helps us to reuse the array

Comment: @Thamilan: I have updated array format now.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the pid in a new array just above :

> $op = array;
>   So everytime buildtree is called the pid is added to the new array.
>   You can add other arrays in the resultant $op array after it is returned.

This should be done outside buildtree method:
Check if there is any element whose parent_id is not in the new array that was created if yes then add that element to $op as per the requirement.

Hope that helps.